# What damage bonuses apply to Come and Get It?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, damage

The text of the power of Come and Get It reads:

> You pull the target up to 2 squares, but only if it can end the pull adjacent to you. If the target is adjacent to you after the pull, it takes 1[W] damage.

According to some forum posts I've seen it seems like some enhancement and feat bonuses should apply.

I have two specific bonus questions though:

1. Typed damage (e.g. cold) added by various bits of equipment (e.g. Gloves of Ice) that say "+2 to damage rolls" - I assume RAW interpretation here is that it counts, but just double checking.
2. Damage from Iron Armbands of Power. The wording here is not clear if the damage from Come and Get It is melee damage. Here is the item text:

   > Gain a +4 item bonus to melee damage rolls

So what I am looking at for a +3 greataxe is:
1d12 + 3 + feat bonus + cold item bonus? + armbands item bonus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Come and Get it is a **close burst** power, clearly stated in the power summary. Not melee, so Iron Armbands of Power do not apply. Gloves of Ice only adds damage, if your power does cold damage or has the cold keyword anyway.
Feat and Enhancement bonuses do apply normally.

Comment: As a sidenote: it is quite strange that you have a +3 weapon, level 11-15, while you have a 16th level arm slot item.

Comment: yes, you're right, but this is a rebuilt character and i had to re-apportion the gold for my items and i chose to spend a bit less on the weapon in favor of some other items.